# Why doesn't Task<TResult>.Result work in this case?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

It is working fine with the following code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task<int> t = test(5);
    Console.WriteLine(t.Result);
}

private Task<int> test(int n)
{
    return Task.Run(() => 
    {
        return n;
    });
}
```

But if I wrap the test method with an async method, it doesn't work:

```
private Task<int> test(int n)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        return n;
    });
}

public async Task<int> wrap()
{
    return await test(5);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task<int> t = wrap();
    Console.WriteLine(t.Result);
}
```

The form loses response. If I use await, it works as expected.

**Update1:** 
These two answers are both correct, but I can only mark one as answer. Based on the understanding of this question, I did further test. I used ConfigureAwait in wrap method to 
leave the continuation to run in thread other than UI:

```
public async Task<int> wrap()
{
    return await test(5).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

It works fine. And then I tested this:

```
public async Task<int> wrap()
{
    int i = await test(5).ConfigureAwait(false);
    int j = i + await test(3);
    return j;
}
```

It's working on the first time when I clicked the button, but deadlock again on second click. If I added ConfigureAwait(false) after test(3), like this:

```
public async Task<int> wrap()
{
    int i = await test(5).ConfigureAwait(false);
    int j = i + await test(3).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return j;
}
```

it's working again, but this doesn't make sense to me. Because of   the first ConfigureAwait(false), all the following synchronization part in wrap() should be run on non-UI thread. I don't understand why the second ConfigureAwait(false) is necessary.

**Update2:**

```
private Task<int> test(int n)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("test(" + n + "): " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        return n;
    });
}

public async Task<int> wrap()
{
    Console.WriteLine("1.wrap(): " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    int i = await test(5).ConfigureAwait(false);
    Console.WriteLine("2.wrap(): " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    int j = i + await test(3);
    Console.WriteLine("3.wrap(): " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    return j;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1.button1_Click(): " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        var t = wrap();
        Console.WriteLine("2.button1_Click(): " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        Console.WriteLine(t.Result);    
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }    
}
```

After several click, the form is freezing, and the output is:

```
1.button1_Click(): 8
1.wrap(): 8 
test(5): 13
2.wrap(): 8
2.button1_Click(): 8 
test(3): 13
```

To my surprise, "2.wrap():" is running in the same thread with "1.wrap():", rather than "test(5)". It seems that the code after the ConfigureAwait(false) can also jump back to UI　ｔｈｒｅａｄ．

Answer (score 4):

It's a deadlock -- two `Task`s running in a single-threaded scheduler are waiting for each-other to complete.

Two very important things to understanding this:

- By default, the result of an `await` comes back on the same scheduler as it started in.
- The UI runs on a single-threaded event loop, and the immediate scheduler available to `await` in UI calls is one which dispatches onto this event loop. Only a single Task can be executing at once in this scheduler.

Because of these, you need to be *especially* careful about how you call blocking methods on a `Task` which executes inside of the UI's scheduler.

In your second example, the call to `Result` is waiting for the continuation setup in `wrap` to complete. The continuation is scheduled to be run on the UI thread, which the call to `Result` just happens to be blocking, so neither will ever complete.

Answer (score 3):

You are causing a deadlock which I [explain in detail on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). In summary, the `await` keyword will (by default) capture the current context before the `await` and resume the rest of the `async` method within that context. In this case, that "context" is the UI context, which executes code on the UI thread. So, when your code calls `Result`, it is blocking the UI thread, and when the `await` completes, it can't execute the rest of `wrap` on the UI thread. Thus, deadlock.

The best way to avoid this deadlock is to use `await` instead of `Result` or `Wait` for asynchronous tasks. I.e., change your click method to:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Task<int> t = wrap();
  Console.WriteLine(await t);
}
```